# How to pass parameter to an onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I have a li item that I am passing through to my server to retrieve data from the database, but I am unable to do so:

```
<li name="Physics" value="Physics" id="physics" onclick="drawChart(id)">Physics</li>
```

This drawChart function use google chart API .

```
function drawChart(value) {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "getData.php?subject=value",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
...
```

The getData.php is working fine but I am unable to pass parameter and use it.

Comment: You are using the literal text `value`, not concatenating the actual value of the variable named `value`

Comment: `drawChart(this.id)` and in your function: `url: "getData.php?subject=" + encodeURIComponent(value),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop using inline javascript, and the issue solves it self

```js
$('#physics').on('click', function() {
    drawChart(this.id);
});

function drawChart(value) {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url      : "getData.php",
          data     : {subject : value},
          dataType : "json",
      }).done(function(response) {
          // use response here
      });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li name="Physics" value="Physics" id="physics" >Physics</li>
```

Assuming `$.ajax` in your code is jQuery, why not use more of it ...

Comment: You forgot to concatenate the actual `value`

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in `this` as an argument to the onclick function.

```js
function clickHandler(el) {
  console.log(el.id);
}
```

```html
<button id="clickMe" onclick="clickHandler(this)">Click me</button>
```